# Learning how to map numeric values into an array

Tags: machine-learning

Deal all,

I am looking for an appropriate algorithm which can allow me to learn how some numeric values are mapped into an array.

Try to imagine that I have a training data set like this:

```
1 1 2 4 5 --> [0 1 5 7 8 7 1 2 3 7]
2 3 2 4 1 --> [9 9 5 6 6 6 2 4 3 5]
...
1 2 1 8 9 --> [1 4 5 8 7 4 1 2 3 4]
```

So that given a new set of numeric values, I would like to predict this new array

```
5 8 7 4 2 --> [? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards!

---

Some considerations:

- Let us suppose that all numbers are integer and the length of the arrays is fixed
- Quality of each predicted array can be determine by means of a distance function which try to measure the likeness between the ideal and the predicted array.

Comment: There are no restrictions. But, let us suppose that all numbers are integers, and of course, there is a (unknown) function being able to take the numbers on the left and map them into the array. The question is: how can I try to discover this unknown mapping function?

Comment: Genetic algorithm, neural net, heuristics.... You will have a hard time figuring out a fitness function however. And in case of a neural net, debugging whether it's working or not will be impossible.

But both of these have a chance of producing a valid predicted array.

Comment: @Shark: what do you mean by "debugging will be impossible"?

Comment: @larsmans I mean that, once you get an output from the net, you won't know if it's not working or just untrained enough. It'll be aproximating an unknown function and can only be trained based on input/expected output, with no 'grades of success' in between. At what point you figure out that it's predicting better? :)

Comment: @Salvador Dali, Well, you can have whatever number between 0 and 65535, and both the amount of numbers to be mapped and the length of the arrays is fixed.

Comment: So this will be used to figure out the IVs based on a passphrase? ;)

Comment: @Shark: usually, you measure whether a neural net is predicting what it should be based on a test set. You measure accuracy, log loss or squared error, averaged over that set. All three can be extended to the multi-output case.

Comment: @Shark, the purpose is, given a set of parameters concerning a house (number of home occupants, average age, outdoor temperature, illuminance, number of electrical devices, and so on) trying to predict the energy consumption (in hourly basis) and learn how these parameters are involved. For example, we guess dust presence has not impact at all, but outdoor temperature is decisive in some parts of the day.

Comment: @Jorgemar: that sounds like a typical regression task. Just try any old least-squares implementation and ask over at [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com) when you're stuck.

Comment: @larsmans true, but what I was getting at was along the lines "is it better to have 2/7 numbers guessed right, or have 6/7 numbers be within +/- 1 of ideal guess". Without some sort of a ruling on that I feel the NN would be ineffective... andro saabas pointed out the same concern, which is even more highlighted in the GA case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a challenging task in general. Are your array lengths fixed? What's the loss function (for example is it better to be "closer" for single digits -- is predicting 2 instead of 1 better than predicting 9 or it doesn't matter? Do you get credit for partial matches on the array, such as predicting the first half correct? etc)?

In any case, classical regression or classification techniques would likely not work very well for your scenario. I think the best bet would be to try a [genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) approach.  The fitness function would then be your loss measure i mentioned earlier. You can check this nice [comparison](http://www.tc33.org/genetic-programming/genetic-programming-software-comparison/) for genetic programming libraries for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [structured output problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_prediction), where the target you are trying to predict is a complex structure, rather than a simple class (classification) or number (regression).

As mentioned above, the loss function is an important thing you will have to think about. Minimum edit distance, RMS or simple 0-1 loss could be used.

[Structured support vector machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_support_vector_machine) or variations on ridge regression for structured output problems are two known algorithms that can tackle this problem. See wikipedia of course.

We have a research group on this topic at Universite Laval (Canada), led by Mario Marchand and Francois Laviolette. You might want to search for their publications like "Risk Bounds and Learning Algorithms for the Regression Approach to Structured Output Prediction" by Sebastien Giguere et al.

Good luck!